# SQL select distinct column of one and display all

Tags: sql

I have a table like this

```
ID | course_id | date       | location
1  | 02        | 02-02-2020 | HL
2  | 02        | 02-02-2020 | JL
3  | 13        | 04-02-2020 | BK
4  | 14        | 13-03-2020 | HL
5  | 13        | 18-03-2020 | JL
```

I want to get a table that filters the course_id to only display unique but also get all the other data

```
ID | course_id | date       | location
1  | 02        | 02-02-2020 | HL
3  | 13        | 04-02-2020 | BK
4  | 14        | 13-03-2020 | HL
```

So I will get a result like this.

I have done `SELECT DISTINCT 'course_id' FROM 'course_batches' ORDER BY 'ID' DESC` 
which will only pull out the unique course_id column. 
Then I've tried

```
SELECT *
  FROM 'course_batches' AS a
  JOIN (SELECT DISTINCT(course_id) AS col1 FROM 'course_batches') ORDER BY 'ID' DESC
```

Which returned an error. I might have placed the order wrongly or calling a totally different query but I'm not sure what is wrong here

Comment: Tag your question with the database you are using.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A generic method uses a correlated subquery:

```
select cb.*
from course_batches cb
where cb.id = (select max(cb2.id) from course_batches cb2 where cb2.course_id = cb.course_id);
```

Notes:

- For performance, you want an index on `(course_id, id)`.
- Use meaningful table aliases for your table (`cb` is an abbreviation).
- Only use single quotes for string and date constants -- never for identifiers!